# How to get the id of the table on click - jquery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Let's assume I have a data table with id initialised as "**#id**". But when I inspect the elements I can see the id changed to "**#id_wrapper**". What could be the best possible way to get the original id of the table on clicking a button? Suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Comment: You need to add your code and possibly browser output.

Comment: If you have any code please post it so we can understand better.

Comment: `id` doesn't change by itself, something in your js code changes it. Also, you can use `data-attribute`s to store data, something like `data-original-id="xx"` instead of `id="xx"`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/UvjnT/  please refer this example. check for table id. It has been given as example in html but changed when i inspect the elements.

Answer (score 0):

when you give a id to any table and then apply dataTable function it automatically adds some parent div with the classes like a wrapper the id which you give is under that wrapper div with table like the image shown here [image]

Comment: Exactly, that's my question. How can I get that ID? I have tried other option by setting a data attribute as mentioned by @fen1x. Do you have any solution?

Comment: original id will be there under the table tag =>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example" aria-describedby="example_info">